# Javascript use in Java Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to perform  click operation on button thro' javascript in selenium Webdriver. Below is my javaScript code

```
 JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
            //  js.executeScript("document.getElementById('customerid').click();");

           js.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('ms-crm-ImageStrip-btn_off_lookup ms-crm-Lookup').click();");
```

Below is my HTML code

```
td class="Lookup_RenderButton_td" style="width: 21px">
<img id="customerid" class="ms-crm-ImageStrip-btn_off_lookup ms-crm-Lookup" defaultviewid="{A9AF0AB8-861D-4CFA-92A5-C6281FED7FAB}" savedquerytype="" isdisplayonly="false" resolveemailaddress="0" showproperty="1" disableviewpicker="0" disablequickfind="0" disablemru="0" allowfilteroff="1" autoresolve="1" defaulttype="1" lookupstyle="single" lookupbrowse="0" lookuptypeicons="/_imgs/ico_16_1.gif?ver=-1567689440:/_imgs/ico_16_2.gif?ver=-1567689440" lookuptypenames="account:1:Account,contact:2:Contact" crmattributeid="{09d25a7a-420f-42f7-bad4-192edc51356a}" lookuptypes="1,2" attrpriv="7" attrname="customerid" style="ime-mode:auto" req="2" alt="Click to select a value for Customer Name." src="/_imgs/btn_on_lookup.png" title="Click to select a value for Customer Name." forcesubmit="false"/>
<a tabindex="-1" onclick="Mscrm.Utilities.click(previousSibling);" href="#" title="Click to select a value for Customer Name."/>
</td>
```

Exception I am getting   :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: document.getElementsByClassName(...).click is not a function
Command duration or timeout: 12 milliseconds
```

Can anyone check where i am doing mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use any one:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('ms-crm-ImageStrip-btn_off_lookup ms-crm-Lookup')[0].click();")
```

or

```
content = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ms-crm-ImageStrip-btn_off_lookup ms-crm-Lookup')
content.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` will return list of elements, not an element.

Not tested, try

```
js.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('ms-crm-ImageStrip-btn_off_lookup ms-crm-Lookup')[0].click();");
```

(add `[0]` after calling of `getElementsByClassName` function)